python script crashes on Windows; fixed by running a separate memory update py script
I have a Python Flask API server that crashes after a few seconds when running on my new Windows machine (a Dell work station). There is usually no error message, but sometimes there are errors related to Python libraries (not my code).

This same program runs stably and without errors on 5 other Windows machines with the same OS version (but lower hardware specifications).
here' another possible error message (varied from time to time)


Yesterday,
I made a new discovery: I wrote an unrelated Python script that continuously updates memory information (updates an array variable, takes up 1K of memory) in a while True loop. When I run this update_memory script and then start the Flask server, the Flask program runs normally and does not exit.
However, as soon as I close the update_memory script, the Flask program immediately terminates automatically. Again, there is usually no error message, but sometimes there are errors related to Python libraries (still, not my code).

Additional Details:
When the Flask py script quits, there's always this event in Windows eventvwr. It goes like:
EventData 

python.exe 
3.10.6150.1013 
62e84c21 
python310.dll 
3.10.6150.1013 
62e84bd6 
c0000005 
0000000000073fe5 
36f0 
01dad2a089e5de44 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.dll 
ac4f916b-29e0-4081-9ea1-b4640148abe9 

I noticed that there is a "c0000005" in it and did some research, it could be something related to memory. So I wrote the update_memory script and shocked by what happened.

BTW, I have installed different windows OS version (win10, win11) on this machine, but  always the same kind of error, no exception, no miracle.
I suspect a hardware issue or hardware compatibility issue. How can I continue to investigate this further?

If You Are Getting Error On Windows I Suggest Using Ubuntu Terminal With wsl you can find it on Microsoft store.
Try there and let me know if that works

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

After replace the CPU i9-13900k with another 12th gen intel CPU, everything works just fine. No more breakdown.
I read this(intel 13/14th CPU issue) couple days ago and I think the case can be closed now.
